# Carmen-rails undefined method "-"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carmen

Using carmen-rails to generate a country select element in my billing address form.

```
 country_select(:card, :country, {priority: ['United States', 'Canada']}, id: 'country')
```

The above usage causes the following error:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for {:priority=>["United States", "Canada"]}:Hash
```

I have tried leaving out the priority option but the issues remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the result of having other gems installed.

I had installed country-select gem version 1.1.1

To resolve the issue I just had to remove the gem.

```
gem uninstall country-select
```